# Python pdb computes value 774 but program assigns 836

Tags: python, pdb

I'm sure I am missing something here, but I find this very weird.

In `pdb` I get to the following step...

```
 Importing data...
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/scroll/marching_cube.py(111)read_data()
-> n_cubes = int((n_slices - n_input_z) * int(math.ceil((x_dimension - n_input_x)/step_size)) * int(math.ceil((y_dimension - n_input_y)/step_size)))
```

When I compute the right hand side of the assignment, I get `774` -- which is the correct value. I can prove it by doing the computation directly in `pdb`...

```
(Pdb) int((n_slices - n_input_z) * int(math.ceil((x_dimension - n_input_x)/step_size)) * int(math.ceil((y_dimension - n_input_y)/step_size)))
774
```

But watch this... when I go to the next line via the `n` command, `n_cubes` is suddenly assigns the value `836`...

```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/scroll/marching_cube.py(111)read_data()
-> n_cubes = int((n_slices - n_input_z) * int(math.ceil((x_dimension - n_input_x)/step_size)) * int(math.ceil((y_dimension - n_input_y)/step_size)))
(Pdb) int((n_slices - n_input_z) * int(math.ceil((x_dimension - n_input_x)/step_size)) * int(math.ceil((y_dimension - n_input_y)/step_size)))
774
(Pdb) n
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/scroll/marching_cube.py(112)read_data()
-> input_4d_volume = np.empty((n_cubes,n_input_z,n_input_x,n_input_y))
(Pdb) n_cubes
836
```

To prove the computation should be `774` I will print out all variables involved in the computation...

```
(Pdb) n_slices
49
(Pdb) n_input_z
48
(Pdb) x_dimension
396
(Pdb) n_input_x
48
(Pdb) step_size
8
(Pdb) y_dimension
198
(Pdb) n_input_y
48
```

Comment: what is the value of `n_cubes` prior to `line 111's` execution?

Comment: @CraigBurgler not defined, if I set it equal to zero before, I get the same results

Comment: are you using threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644521/python-variable-is-evaluated-differently-in-pdb-and-print-statements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821565/python-pdb-debugger-gets-confused-when-python-method-called-after-a-tree-but-ope?s=7|0.5485

Comment: I am using threads, Tensorflow session. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: see my answer for a suggested approach

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the breakpoint at the start of the function being run as a thread, or within its `while true:` loop if it has one, by adding this:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Then run the script normally (*not* through `pdb`) and execution will break into the debugger when the thread starts. Setting a breakpoint this way allows `pdb` to be run within the child thread where it will have access to `n_cubes's` value.

Comment: This is actually how I have been debugging. Anywhere I want to examine code, I set `pdb.set_trace()`. Am I missing something?